# Updated LaTeX Bundle for TextMate

Tags: textmate

Where can I download an updated version of the LaTeX Bunble for TextMate (I'm still using v.1.5.10). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As most other bundles, on GitHub:

#### [latex.tmbundle](https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle)

It's easiest to update through [GetBundles](https://gist.github.com/2722805) though.

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles
cd !$
svn co http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Review/Bundles/GetBundles.tmbundle/
osascript -e 'tell app "TextMate" to reload bundles'
```

Then, visit *Bundles » GetBundles » Get Bundles* and search for "LaTeX".

Comment: Just curious, anything wrong with the shipped one?

Comment: It has some outdated elements (e.g., Latexmk.pl).